# How to manage unauthorized request error response using laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, response, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel 10.17.1 and passport 11.* for API.

I have added multi authentication for passport, like this in config/auth.php :

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'user-api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],
    'customer-api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => User::class,
    ],
    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Customer::class,
    ],
],
```

And also updated scope app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php :

```
public function boot(): void
{
    Passport::tokensCan([
        'user' => 'User Type',
        'customer' => 'Customer User Type',
    ]);

}
```

Updated scope class in app/Http/Kernel.php in `$middlewareAliases` array for passport :

```
'scopes' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckScopes::class,
    'scope' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyScope::class,
```

Add routes for API :

```
Route::middleware([
    'api',
    ])->prefix('api')->group(function () {
        
    Route::post('customer/login',[ApiAuthController::class, 'customerLogin'])->name('customer.Login');
    Route::group( ['prefix' => 'customer','middleware' => ['auth:customer-api','scopes:customer'] ],function(){
        Route::get('dashboard',[ApiCustomerController::class, 'clientDashboard']);
        Route::get('/',[ApiCustomerController::class, 'getCustomer']);
    });
});
```

Function  view like this ApiAuthController.php :

```
public function customerLogin(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()->all()]);
    }

    $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
    if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt($credentials)) {
        $tokenMenager = Auth::guard('customer')->user()->createToken('cutomerToken', ['customer']);
        $success ['token'] = $tokenMenager->accessToken;
        $success ['customer'] = Auth::guard('customer')->user();

        return $this->sendResponse($success, "Customer login successfully.");
        } else {
                return response()->json([
                        'error' => 'Incorrect email or password.',
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

Function view like this ApiCustomerController.php :

```
/**
 * Get customer data
 */
public function getCustomer()
{
    return $this->sendResponse(auth()->user(), 'Customer collection');
}
```

And also changed Authenticate.php Middleware file like this :

```
protected function redirectTo(Request $request): ?string
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 401,
                'message' => 'Unauthorized',
            ], 401);
            // return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => "Unauthorized Request"], 401);
        } elseif ($request->getHttpHost() == config('constants.app_host')) {
            return route('admin.login');
        } else {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

When I hit login API, I got token in response, and then add the token to get customer API, and this API checks authentication, if I don't sent token with request, It will redirect to login page, because I have changed Authenticate.php file, now I also want to update for API request and I have added the response as JSON, but in response, I am getting this below error:

> ErrorException: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in file /var/www/html/photoapp/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php on line 376

[image]

How can I send error message in response if customer is unauthorized ?